# Vue .sync on kebab-case prop cannot handle update event

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to code a Vue .sync demo.I'm confused about when I use kebab-case prop, it can't listen update event. Like this.

```
<sync-input v-bind:input-value.sync="message"></sync-input>

Vue.component('sync-input',{
    props:{
        inputValue: String
    },
    template: `
        <div>
            <label>{{inputValue}}</label>
            <input type="text" v-bind:value="inputValue" v-on:input="$emit('update:input-value', $event.target.value)">
        </div>
    `
})
```

But if I use single word prop,it works.

```
<sync-input v-bind:title.sync="message"></sync-input>

Vue.component('sync-input',{
    props:{
        title: String
    },
    template: `
        <div>
            <label>{{title}}</label>
            <input type="text" v-bind:value="title" v-on:input="$emit('update:title', $event.target.value)">
        </div>
    `
})
```

Is there any wrong with my code? Or it's a bug?

Comment: Not used to this, but just curious: what happens if you try to define the props object with the kebab key: `{'input-value': String}`?

Comment: @Sergeon as same as defining with `{'inputValue': String}` or `{inputValue: String}`. The problem has not been solved.

Comment: I'm not sure why this happenes whith kebab-case, but you could try caramelCase
`:inputValue.sync=""`

Comment: @SølveTornøe it doesn't work.